# Excel VBA - Create multiple data strings on a weekly basis from start date to ending date

Tags: excel, ms-office, vba

How can I have some code repeat a range of data in a row (from column B to G) into the following rows until there is an empty cell in row A?

The code I pulled together is here below.

```
Sub AddFlight_Click()

Dim NextRow As Long, LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet, ColumnA As Range

Set ws = Sheets("JetAir Flight Plan")
NextRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ColumnA = ws.Range ("A:A")

 'Data inserted in a userform are assigned to specific cells in a sheet. 

    ws.Range("A" & NextRow).Value = StartingFlightDateComboBox.Text
    ws.Range("P" & "2").Value = EndingFlightDateComboBox.Text
    ws.Range("B" & NextRow).Value = DayOfWeekComboBox.Text
    ws.Range("D" & NextRow).Value = ETATextBox.Text
    ws.Range("E" & NextRow).Value = TourOperatorTextBox.Text
    ws.Range("F" & NextRow).Value = FlightNumberTextBox.Text
    ws.Range("G" & NextRow).Value = FromToTextBox.Text
    ws.Range("H" & NextRow).Value = AllotmentTextBox.Text

     'A series of dates is created from a starting date 
     '    to an ending date in column A.

   ws.Range("A" & NextRow).Select
   Selection.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlChronological, Date:= _
       xlDay, Step:=7, Stop:=ws.Range("P" & "2").Value, Trend:=False

  'The data filled in the last row with the userform data through
  ' the first part of the macro will be copied and pasted in 
  ' the next row until there is a blank cell in column A.

Do While ColumnA(i) <> ""
ws.Range("B" & LastRow).Resize(, 6).Copy

Loop

End Sub
```

I can't make the last part work. One error I receive is the ColumnA error: Runtime error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set.

But I set it as Range("A:A"). Any better way to write that code?

Any suggestions as to why?

Thanks.

Comment: Typically here on SO you're expected to post some existing code (even if it doesn't quite work) when asking for help.  At the very least you need to ask a *specific" question about some aspect of your project you're having a problem with. Questions which are a set of requirements followed by "Someone please write this for me"  typically get closed pretty quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will try and create a rough version myself then, and ask for help later.

Comment: @TimWilliams I tried to solve it myself, but I got stuck at the final point. The code is up in the text. Given that I didn't know what code was a week ago, I feel very happy about what I achieved, and even if it was extremely inefficient, I was happy to learn and work my way out of the problems I faced. Can you help me with the last bit of the project? I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub AddFlight_Click()

    Const RNG_END_DT As String = "P2"
    Dim NextRow As Long, LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("JetAir Flight Plan")
    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    NextRow = LastRow + 1

    'Data inserted in a userform are assigned to specific cells in a sheet.
    ws.Range("A" & NextRow).Value = StartingFlightDateComboBox.Text
    ws.Range("B" & NextRow).Value = DayOfWeekComboBox.Text
    ws.Range("D" & NextRow).Value = ETATextBox.Text
    ws.Range("E" & NextRow).Value = TourOperatorTextBox.Text
    ws.Range("F" & NextRow).Value = FlightNumberTextBox.Text
    ws.Range("G" & NextRow).Value = FromToTextBox.Text
    ws.Range("H" & NextRow).Value = AllotmentTextBox.Text
    ws.Range(RNG_END_DT).Value = EndingFlightDateComboBox.Text

    'A series of dates is created from a starting date
    '    to an ending date in column A.
    ws.Range("A" & NextRow).DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, _
        Type:=xlChronological, Date:=xlDay, Step:=7, _
        Stop:=ws.Range(RNG_END_DT).Value, Trend:=False

    'The data filled in the last row with the userform data through
    ' the first part of the macro will be copied and pasted in
    ' the next row until there is a blank cell in column A.
    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range(ws.Range("B" & NextRow), ws.Cells(LastRow, "H")).FillDown

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim. That formula works perfectly. Now I will try to automatise my flight plan process even more by trying to tell Excel to pull the data to do this very job from a data pool on another sheet instead of having to insert it into a Userform for every data row. In case I have a question to post on SO (after having looked for similar posts in order not to create duplications) should I create a new question or follow into this one? I think I should create a new one, as it's a different task I need Excel to do on top of this one. 

Anyways, thanks again and wish me luck! :)

Comment: I would create a new question if you have a new requirement.  And good luck!